# Flutter dart:ffi use static c library .a archive

Tags: flutter, dart, dart-ffi

The documentation is very unclear about how to use a static library that is provided through an archive file (library.a)

> First-party library A first-party native library can be included
>   either as source or as a (signed) .framework file. It’s probably
>   possible to include statically linked archives as well, but it
>   requires testing.
>
> *Source: https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/c-interop#first-party-library*

Has anyone done this before? 
My specific goal is to get this working on iOS.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this?

Comment: Sadly no, I ended up using the lib via an Objective C Plugin

Comment: Ooh, I'm trying to solve the same issue. Hope I'll find a solution.